# How do I react to external program launch inside an Automator workflow?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, automator, sirishortcuts

As per the title, I need to automate unwinding my date 7 days back upon I launch a specific macOS application bundle and putting the timestamp back to normal 45 seconds into its uptime.

What I need to do is:

1. Watch an application bundle with a specific name to be opened (like `FileSystemWatcher` in .NET)
2. Change the date 7 days back between the `Application opened by user` and `First application window appears` events (events written in pseudocode)
3. Wait 40-45 seconds while the application checks the trial period status
4. Wind the date forward to normal state.

It looks like the Automator standard library does not implement a wholly native solution for this part of workflow, and I need to find a workaround. I know it is wrong using non-seamless methods of application integration, like launcher shell scripts, and I do not prefer cracks either, just because they are illegal and also due to the fact of putting a stamp into the application menus, like `K'ed by MacKed team`. This severely damages the eye candy and is too explicit saying the software has indeed been pirated.

I do not endorse nor condone any forms of computer piracy. This question has been asked exclusively for educational purposes.

Comment: Automator can use AppleScripts, but it isn't really the right tool for things like notifications or timers.  Are you sure an application is doing something silly like using system dates to determine a trial period?

Comment: Yes. I read about it on a particular GH gist about Parallels Desktop. Parallels indeed determines the trial period by system date https://gist.github.com/gdurastanti/e79b1fae40a4eff14f5636b8994a89fc?permalink_comment_id=3980703